# Creating a Custom Implementation using Guid and Custom Table names with Asp.net Identity 1.1 Alpha

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I'm drawing from different questions (listed below as I ask the question).

I would like to do five things and as far as I can tell from these questions and answers... all of this can be done in my OnModelCreating method.

**Preface**: I am using the latest nightly bits for Asp.Net Identity 1.1-alpha

- I would like to use "UserId" instead of Id as the property for my
  Users Id in the AspNetUsers table. I understand this would involve
  using "HasColumnName" during OnModelCreating.
- I would like to use Guid (uniqueidentifier) as the data type for my
  UserId (instead of string). I understand that this involves using my
  own POCOS for IUser class and IUserStore, etc as Hao Kung Indicates
  in his answer here...

[How to change type of id in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553424/how-to-change-type-of-id-in-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityus/19577113#19577113)

- I would like to use my own custom table names such as MyRoles,
  MyCUserClaims, MyUserLogins, MyUserRoles, MyUsers as indicated in
  this answer...

[How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity)

- All the foreign keys should be mapped apppropriately with the Asp.net
  Identity tables as Hao Kung shows here...

[Create ASP.NET Identity tables using SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932993/create-asp-net-identity-tables-using-sql-script/20057794#20057794)

- I would like to add properties to the ApplicationUser of FirstName
  and LastName.

So, based on the above... can someone provide me with the OnModelCreating method which would create these Identity tables accordingly, with UserId as the Id column for the users of type Guid (uniqueidentifier), in tables with custom names, with the appropriate foreign key relationships, and with two additional properties on ApplicationUser of FirstName and LastName?

Comment: So you've found all of the related posts on how to do what you want, you just don't want to do it yourself? Have you tried any of it? Did you have issues?

Comment: @Jack Good point. I can do these separately. The problem is I can make it use Guid for an Id (instead of ints) but not when I change the table names. I assume when 1.1 is complete all will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932993/create-asp-net-identity-tables-using-sql-script). His was not the accepted answer for that particular question but [@pwdst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107593/pwdst) posted an answer that includes an OnModelCreating that I modified to do exactly as I was asking here. Last week I asked him to post here so I could accept his answer but he has not done so... therefore I'm answering myself and directing you to [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932993/create-asp-net-identity-tables-using-sql-script).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be looking too linearly at the solution thinking it can be done all in once place.

I would advise the following:

Implement your own [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and override the methods to use the exact tables and logic you would like for interacting with your users. If this is an ASP.NET MVC 4 or newer implementation, you may want to look into the newer SimpleMembership implementation and instead implement [ExtendedMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.extendedmembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx). SimpleMembership by default has a nice UserProfile system that will allow you to add those FirstName, LastName, and other custom properties.

Furthermore, some of the things on your list can be done independent of this implementation if you are using Entity Framework. If you are using code first you can tag the primary key of your model simply by adding the [Key] attribute to the property UserId similar to this. You can also use [Table(String name)] for the table name if it isn't the standard plural form of the POCO. Don't forget to include a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

```
[Table("CustomUsers")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15083137/1228414) is another q/a with many relevant links to implementing your own MembershipProvider.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I did state in my question that this is concerning Asp.net Identity. Simple Membership is an older membership system, Identity is Microsoft's latest.