# User Role/Authorization doesn't work in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

have this (model builder) code on our DbContext.cs

```
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ApplicationUser");
```

Everything works fine except for **Authorization/User Roles**.

After checking all tables I noticed that **IdentityUserRoles** table creates 4 columns: **RoleId, UserId, IdentityRole_Id and ApplicationUser_Id.**

I found out that, **IdentityRole_Id and ApplicationUser_Id** [Foreign Keys] are mapped or used instead of the **RoleId and UserId** [Primary Keys]. Unfortunately, identity (Id's) data were inserted in RoleId/UserId column and IdenityRole_Id/ApplicationUser_Id are **NULL** by default.

Please help.

My Code:

```
public class RqDbContext : DbContext
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "RqDbContext";

    public RqDbContext() : base(ConnectionString)
    {
    }
    public static RqDbContext Create()
    {
        return new RqDbContext();
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Data Tables
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CompanyAccount> CompanyAccounts { get; set; }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Security
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public DbSet<ApplicationUserExtend> ApplicationUserExtends { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ApplicationUser");

    }

} 

public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    //custom+
    public virtual ApplicationUserExtend Extend { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationUserExtend
{
    public ApplicationUserExtend()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Id")]
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Display(Name="Account Id")]
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name="Active Account Id")]
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int ActiveAccountId { get; set; }
}



public class RqInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<RqDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(RqDbContext context)
    {

        var testData = ReadTestData();

        AddIdentityRoles(context, testData);
        AddUsers(context, testData);

        MvcUtil.SaveChanges(context);
    }

    private void AddUsers(RqDbContext context, TestDataDo testData)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        //Roles.Enabled("user","member");
        var userIndex = 0;

        foreach (var applicationUser in testData.ApplicationUsers)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = applicationUser.UserName,
                Email = applicationUser.Email,
                PhoneNumber = applicationUser.PhoneNumber
            };

            if (userIndex > testData.ApplicationUserExtends.Count)
            {
                throw new Exception("Make sure you the number of rows in ApplicationUserExtends, matches the number of rows in Users");
            }

            user.Extend = new ApplicationUserExtend
            {
                AccountId = testData.ApplicationUserExtends[userIndex++].AccountId
            };

            userManager.Create(user, applicationUser.Password);
            //set User Role
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, applicationUser.Role);

            //context.Users.Add(user);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    private void AddIdentityRoles(RqDbContext context, TestDataDo testData)
    {
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        foreach (var role in testData.IdentityRoles)
        {
            var identity = new IdentityRole(role.Name);

            roleManager.Create(identity);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static TestDataDo ReadTestData()
    {
        var xml = GetResource("Rq.Web.App_Specification.Rq-TestData.xml");
        return XmlUtil.SerializeFromString<TestDataDo>(xml);
    }

    private static string GetResource(string file)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return ResourceUtil.GetAsString(assembly, file);
    }
}

// Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<RqDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}

// Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is in your model builder section. There shouldn't be IdenityRole_Id/ApplicationUser_Id columns in your role table, post your DbContext and ApplicationUser class codes. What is the asp.net identity version?

Comment: The problem is your fluent configuration you've added here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Chris, basically we're trying to extend ApplicationUser table. I have re-posted my code above please check.

Comment: @DSR, "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45"

Answer (score 3):

The code below will fix IdentityUserRoles table Foreign Keys issue.

```
var user = modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>()
    .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
user.HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
user.HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId);
user.Property(u => u.UserName).IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<TUserRole>()
    .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
    .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

modelBuilder.Entity<TUserLogin>()
    .HasKey(l => new { l.UserId, l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey})
    .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

modelBuilder.Entity<TUserClaim>()
    .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

var role = modelBuilder.Entity<TRole>()
    .ToTable("AspNetRoles");
role.Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired();
role.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
```

I found my answer here. [Create ASP.NET Identity tables using SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932993/create-asp-net-identity-tables-using-sql-script)!