# About DbContext in an ASP.NET Identity environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Following up this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity), I have a question to ask.

If I create the class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That means I have to add all my *business logic model domain classes* into that `DbContext` or it is possible to add a second one?

Comment: Assuming you have already tried adding a second context, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: You can create a second one with the same connection string name. It'll work. If you use Migrations, you'll have to enable migrations and run update database on them separately, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have another `DbContext` but the question is whether you want to. See [Entity Framework: One Database, Multiple DbContexts. Is this a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea)

So in your case, if the entities in your domain model are separate from the `IdentityDbContext` then by all means create a new one for those entities. If they rely on anything from `IdentityDbContext` you will need to use that context for your domain entities. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to query across both.