# Duplicate foreign keys when renaming ASP.NET Identity tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity

I followed the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity) to rename my ASP.NET Identity tables:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
```

However this results in two properties for the UserClaim to User relation - `UserId` and `IdentityUser_Id`:

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: One Foreign Key one Primary Key what is the issue?

Comment: the problem here is that the UserId field is the one that should be the foreign key not the auto generated 'IdentityUser_Id' so the foreign key relationship with the Users table is broken. I have encountered this issue but never managed to escape it with my custom names in place i had to revert back to the default name,, if you figured it out please let me know,,, oh one more thing i could not re-set the foreign key using the fluent API  . @MarkHomer

Comment: @Mark `IdentityUser_Id` should not be there as it's an unnecessary duplicate of `UserId`. `UserId` should be the foreign key.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should skip the following line, then it works perfectly well:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");
```

So the only mapping you need is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hunted high and low for a resolution to this problem! Worked perfectly, many thanks

Comment: Spent way too long on this. I kept trying to add my own foreign keys and could not believe it was a simple change. This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identi) lead me to believe it was required.

Comment: There was a [msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/) (see comment section @Giang) that had code sample on how to rename `AspNetUsers` table that I think a lot of people saw, which led them to believe adding `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");` was the right way, when actually it isn't.