# SqlException with Creating User, after changing IdentityUser primary key from string to int

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

After I've followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) to change the type of Application User Id from string to int, I get SqlException if I try to create a new user.

The exact error is:

**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id' table 'DBNAME.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.**

```
Line 208:                };
Line 209:
Line 210:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
Line 211:                if (result.Succeeded)
Line 212:                {

Source File: C:\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\Controllers\MembersController.cs    Line: 210 

[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'DBNAME.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.]
```

Here is the screenshot of AspNetUsers table design view:
[image]

I've looked at [How to tell the primary key 'Id' of IdentityUser class is IDENTITY(1,1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940228/how-to-tell-the-primary-key-id-of-identityuser-class-is-identity1-1)
and [ASP.NET Identity - Error when changing User ID Primary Key default type from string to int AND when using custom table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284610/asp-net-identity-error-when-changing-user-id-primary-key-default-type-from-str) but couldn't help me much.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that Identity is no longer generating a key for you - it did before.

For this problem to work you need to get the key automatically generated by a database. To get this done you need to apply the following attributes on your `Id` property in `ApplicationUser` class:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public override int Id { get; set; }
```

And add another DB-migration to make sure the database knows what to do with this field.

**UPD**: oops. Just noticed that you already link to my identical answer. Does this not help?

Comment: I did the same but nothing good happens, also the migration file shows empty.

Comment: Migration might be a problem here. I remember I had to drop and re-create the table for the migrations to pick up on this change. Try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049305/809357) to make your `Id` column to become `Identity(1,1)`