# Renaming default table names in asp.net mvc project without breaking foreign keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-6.1

I Created a new **MVC 5** project **whenever i try to rename the table names** as described in this *question*

[Change table names using the new Identity system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity)

It always breaks the *foreign key relationships* in the Logins, Claims, Roles tables.

I have tried to override the OnModelCreating method but in vein here is my code

---

> ```
>     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
>     {
>         //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
>         if (modelBuilder == null)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
>         }
>         modelBuilder.Entity<App>().HasKey(m => new { m.AppId, m.FacebookId });
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Admins");
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().
>             Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("AdminId");
>         modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>()
>             .ToTable("Admins")
>             .Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("AdminId");
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("Logins")
>            .HasKey(m => new { m.ProviderKey, m.UserId, m.LoginProvider })
>            .Property(m => m.UserId)
>            .HasColumnName("AdminId");  
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AdminRoles")
>             .HasKey(m => new { m.RoleId, m.UserId })
>             .Property(m => m.RoleId)
>             .HasColumnName("AdminRoleId");
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().Property(m => m.UserId)
>             .HasColumnName("AdminId");
>         //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasRequired(m => m.UserId);
>         //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasRequired(m => m.UserId);
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("Claims")
>             .HasKey(m=> m.Id)
>             .Property(m => m.Id)
>             .HasColumnName("ClaimId");
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles")
>             .HasKey(m => m.Id).Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");
>     }
> ```

where the "Admin" Class is my name for the ApplicationUser Default class plus my own implementation of it

> ```
> public class Admin : IdentityUser
> {
>     [Required]
>     public virtual List<App> Apps { get; set; }
>     public bool? IsPremium { get; set; }
>     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
>     public DateTime? LastPublishDateTime { get; set; }
> }
> ```

**here are my other domain classes**

> ```
> public class App
> {
>     [Key]
>     [Column("AppId", Order = 1)]
>     public virtual int AppId { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     [Key]
>     [Column("FacebookId", Order = 2)]
>     public virtual string FacebookId { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     public virtual string Secret { get; set; }      
>     public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
>     public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     public virtual Admin Admin { get; set; }
> }
>
>
> public class Post
> {
>     [Key]
>     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
>     public virtual int PostId { get; set; }
>     public virtual string Title { get; set; }
>     public virtual string Content { get; set; }
>     public virtual string Link { get; set; }
>     public virtual string Image { get; set; }
>     public virtual bool IsSpecial { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     public virtual App App { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     public virtual DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class User
> {
>     [Key]
>     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
>     public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
>     [MaxLength(500)]
>     public virtual string FacebookId { get; set; }
>     [MaxLength(500)]
>     public virtual string Token { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     public virtual App App { get; set; }
> }
> ```