# How to change table names for ASP.net Identity 2.0 with int ID columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I've used ASP.net membership for years and am just starting to try out ASP.net Identity. They just released version 2.0 and which is supposed to support `int` primary keys. I've defined my custom identity classes as follows in order to get integer primary key support:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{  
}

public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
}

public class Role : IdentityRole<int, UserRole>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }  // Custom description field on roles
}

public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
}

public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
{
}

public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public MyDbContext() : this("MyDB") { }

    public MyDbContext(string connStringName) : base(connStringName)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I create a database migration, it properly creates an integer Id column for each of the identity tables, however, it is ignoring my custom table names specified in the `OnModelCreating` method. Instead I get table names like `dbo.AspNetUsers` and `dbo.AspNetRoles`.

I've also tried adding the `[Table("TableName")]` to my custom identity classes and it has no effect.

In looking at examples for ASP.net Identity 1.0, it looked like they repeated each of the `modelBuilder.Entry<Type>().ToTable("TableName")` lines using the base Identity classes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser<int, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserClaim<int>>>().ToTable("Users");

modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<int, UserRole>>().ToTable("Roles");

modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("UserRoles");

modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>().ToTable("UserLogins");

modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
```

However, I tried several variations and my migrations would not generate. I kept receiving errors similar to **The type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'4[System.Int32,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin'1[System.Int32],Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole'1[System.Int32],Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim'1[System.Int32]]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.**

How can I generate custom table names with integer primary keys in ASP.net Identity 2.0?

Comment: if you happen to land here looking for identity 3.0, [check out this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523066/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-used-by-asp-net-identity-3-vnext). +1s all around

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Grrr...... So after wasting a couple hours on this, I copied my rules and pasted them below the `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` line and everything worked properly. I didn't realize that the base method needed to be called first :(

Everything is working properly now using the following configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
}
```

Comment: Point of interest - base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);   Worked for me as well.. :)

Comment: lifesaver of a post, needing to call base imp first was not intuative at all. If using Identity 2.0, the model types are IdentityRole, IdentityUser, IdentityUseRole, etc... but the same principal applies.

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you find out base.OnModelCreating had to call first?

Comment: Hi Sam corrects me if I am wrong. Just wondering how your code was worked without defines the keys on tables.

Comment: My entities inherited from the Identity classes which already have keys defined. All the code above does is modify the configuration to use different table names

Comment: Note that if you have a derived class (custom role) from IdentityRole, for example, you must indicate that you use the same table for both entities: base class role, and the derived role.`modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");` and `modelBuilder.Entity<DerivedRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");`

Answer (score 8):

In the IdentityModel.cs file, I added the following code to the `ApplicationDbContext` class

Notice the Model names are different that that names listed in the accepted answer

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("SystemUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("SystemRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("SystemUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("SystemUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("SystemUserClaims");
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to change this permanent, event changing the following code it should remain as well