# extending PrimaryKey of IdentityUserRole in Identity 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-identity-2

Is it possible to extend primary key of ApplicationUserRole by additional column?

by default there are two columns defined as primary key: `UserId` and `RoleId`

here is default implementation

```
public partial class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityUserRole<TKey>
{
    public IdentityUserRole();

    // Summary:
    //     RoleId for the role
    public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     UserId for the user that is in the role
    public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
}
```

and the table in a db looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

but i need more! :)
i mean i want my model looks like

```
public partial class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{

    public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }

}
```

I can't understand how to do it in a correct way with data annotations or fluent api. I've tried both without any succes.
It seems migration engine ignores any primary key changes of that model.
At least when i add annotation or fluent api methods migration engine generates empty migration script.

i just added serviceId property and my table now looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ServiceId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and when i try to apply key changes via annotations or fluent api
migration script looks like

```
public partial class rolesmigrate02 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(hk => new { hk.UserId, hk.RoleId, hk.ServiceId});
```

annotations

```
public partial class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public override string UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public override string RoleId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

i can do changes manualy in a db but i doubt
where is my mistake? why i can't extend this model by code first migration?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432357/cant-extend-identityuserrole-cs-to-add-new-composite-key-to-dbo-aspnetuserroles/34545084#34545084

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some time i've found this post [Sam about identity 2 on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855666/3790414)

The Key thing was in `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)`

if we want to reapply or modify predefined identity 2 mappings we should do it AFTER base.OnModelCreating.

so fluent api should look like

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // usualy i put this line to the end of this method but it should be before
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(hk => new { hk.UserId, hk.RoleId, hk.ServiceId});
    }
```