# Can't extend IdentityUserRole.cs to add new composite key to dbo.AspNetUserRoles table ASP.NET Identity 2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, user-roles

I am trying to build Membership system using ASP.NET Identity 2.1, ASP.NET Web API 2.2 and i need to extend `IdentityUserRole` to add another PK to its table like that:

```
public class ApplicationUserRoles : IdentityUserRole
{
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        ProjectId = new Guid();
    }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

And in the DBcontext class I added :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRoles>().HasKey(m => new {m.ProjectId, m.UserId, m.RoleId}).ToTable("ApplicationUserRoles");

}

public DbSet<ApplicationUserRoles> ApplicationUserRoles { get; set; }
```

and this did not work at all , i do not what i did wrong , add migration keep generate :

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.ApplicationUserRoles",
        c => new
            {
                UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                ProjectId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Projects", t => t.ProjectId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
        .Index(t => t.ProjectId);

}
```

As you can see  `PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })`. I need it to be `PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ProjectId,t.UserId, t.RoleId })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work finally and here what i did :

at the signature of IdentityUser myApplicationUser inherits from it

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>
    where TLogin : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TRole : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole<TKey>
    where TClaim : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
{

}
```

it accepts my custom definition of IdentityUserRole.

my class ApplicationUser i needed to implement the right type:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserSecurityProfile, IdentityUserClaim>
{

}
```

and my role:

```
public class ApplicationSecurityProfile : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserSecurityProfile>
{
}
```

and my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationSecurityProfile, string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserSecurityProfile, IdentityUserClaim>, IContext
{

}
```

and my UserStore:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationSecurityProfile, string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserSecurityProfile, IdentityUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

and myRoleStore :

```
 public class ApplicationSecurityProfileStore : RoleStore<ApplicationSecurityProfile, string, ApplicationUserSecurityProfile>
    {
        public ApplicationSecurityProfileStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }


    }
```

then i used my custom classes in the my custom mangers :

RoleManger :

```
public class ApplicationSecurityProfileManager : RoleManager<ApplicationSecurityProfile>
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ApplicationSecurityProfileManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationSecurityProfile, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }



public static ApplicationSecurityProfileManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSecurityProfileManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {

        var appRoleManager = new ApplicationSecurityProfileManager(new ApplicationSecurityProfileStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

        return appRoleManager;
    }

}
```

my UserManager

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var appDbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var appUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(appDbContext));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        appUserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(appUserManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        appUserManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        appUserManager.EmailService = new AspNetIdentity.WebApi.Services.EmailService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            appUserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
            {
                //Code for email confirmation and reset password life time
                TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(6)
            };
        }

        return appUserManager;
    }
}
```

and it works finally