# How do I filter Users by Role Id

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

How do i filter users by role id in asp.net.identity 3.0?

> I can't navigate to Roles (x => x.Roles) anymore.

**Prior version (Asp.net.identity 2.0)**

I had been filtering users by role id as following

```
List<ApplicationUser> adminUsers = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Any(y => y.RoleId == testAdminId || y.RoleId == adminId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Why can't you navigate to Roles?  Do you not have the relationship in your models?

Comment: @Brad have a look at this post to get answer to your question. Please let me know what you understand becuase 
 I still couldn't find the way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946711/get-user-with-assigned-roles

Comment: Does `_context.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role).Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.RoleId == adminId)).ToList()` work?

Comment: @Brad, thanks i shall give a try soon and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @Brad it does not work. Basically i am using AspNetCoreIdentity 3 and i think they have taken off Roles navigation property from Users.

Comment: Can you add the relationship in your own `ApplicationUser` class?

Comment: The navigation properties have been removed in .NET Core 2.0.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x under the heading **Add IdentityUser POCO Navigation Properties**.  I can post this as an answer if you like.