# How can I change the table names used by asp.net identity 3 (vnext)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

The method used in asp.net identity 2 to alter the identity table names does not work in asp.net identity 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily by changing the entity mapping with extension method `ToTable("TableName")`on `OnModelCreating` of your `DbContext`:

And you don't need to use `.ForSqlServerToTable()`, just `.ToTable()` should work in any database.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users"); // Your custom IdentityUser class
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserTokens");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");            
}
```

The only catch here is to remember to use the generics with the type of your identifier (string is default on AspNetCore.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the builder entities in OnModelCreating of your ApplicationDbContext, using ForSqlServerToTable extension method to change the desired table(s) name.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ForSqlServerToTable("Users");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ForSqlServerToTable("UserRoles");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ForSqlServerToTable("UserLogins");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ForSqlServerToTable("UserClaims");
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ForSqlServerToTable("Roles");                        
        }
    }
```

Comment: worked for me with plain old `ToTable` instead of `ForSqlServerToTable`. (though i was using asp.net core identity with dotnet core sample project so, might not help you)