# Asp.Net MVC 5 Identity user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have created a new project with asp.net MVC5.  I am trying to use the MVC5 methods to register and login. I have also changed the default connection of the database to my custom database connection.

The problem starts here:

When the user try to register the mvc5 generates his custom tables like:

- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserClaims
- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUsers

**i want to make him use my custom tables forexample instead of use aspnetusers i want to used dbo.Profile.**

when i've done some research on the internet i have found this article:
[How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity)

i have done the same thing that there is in that article. **The problem is that the mvc5 is using my custom table but it is still generating those tables mentioned above. is there a way to make him stop generating those tables**

any help please to make him generating those tables please????

Comment: Did you check the last part of the question that you followed? According to the -- UPDATE ANSWER -- part of the question, this issue (creating of standard tables) was solved.

Comment: If you’re still struggling with this issue, please post your original code so that we might help you further.

Comment: thanks for your comments i am going to try the answer below if this  won't work i will post my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the line:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
```

like here:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");

    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help i will try this and will let you now if helped