# How to change table name using database first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

This is similar to this question but with using database first entity framework instead of code first:
[How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity)

In the code first approach you can override OnModelCreating and do something like this so that the user info is saved in MyUsers table instead of the default AspNetUsers:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("MyUsers")
```

In the database first approach I have manually created the MyUsers table but because OnModelCreating does not get called I don't know how to configure the data to be saved into my new table?

Comment: did you find this answer somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Code First approach an when overriding the OnModelCreating add the line:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
```

The line above will link the AspNetIdentity entities to your tables without re-creating the tables.

Code Example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");

    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
}
```

Comment: Hi Freerider. The OnModelCreating method does not get called?  I guess this is because I'm using a database first approach which is my requirement for this

Comment: Is your Database Context (ApplicationDbContext in my example) inheriting from IdentityDbContext?

Comment: Actually no, I'm inheriting from DbContext. Do I need to inherit from IdentityDbContext? I did inherit from it now and OnModelCreating still didn't get called. I think if I change the connecting string to a code-first string it will get called but I need to do this in a database-first way. And advice or a link to a useful example of this?

Comment: @Bob did you find a way to make it work with DatabaseFirst approach?