# Renamed default tables but AspNetusers Table Still Getting Created

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am working with ASP.NET identity. I renamed the default tables using the following code.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    }
}
```

}

But when I run my app, AspnetUsers is still created but with a single column named 'Id'. This table is being populated along with the new "Users" table. Why? And how do I stop this behavior.

I see the same question asked here, but without a good response: [Identity 2.0 Code First Table Renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016684/identity-2-0-code-first-table-renaming)

I hope I am not violating StackOverflow's guidelines in reasking this question/// if so apologies in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this post when looking for a quick solution - now I've dug a bit through the code and found the answer; maybe it helps someone.

I suppose you have overwritten the default IdentityUser class, right?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
...
```

In that case, you'll have to exclude the default IdentityUser from the ModelBuilder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users", "dbo"); // we have overwritten IdentityUser, so no more need for the empty AspNetUsers table
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users", "dbo"); // Use ApplicationUser instead
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles", "dbo");
```