# Rename PhoneNumber to MobileNumber and use PhoneNumber as an additional column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2 with EF. In ASP.NET Identity I have PhoneNumber property which in my case(business wise) is mobile-number. But I also have Phone-Number which I am using for as office-phone. Now I want all my code use MobileNumber(for mobile) and PhoneNumber(for office). I can do something like this, [How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity) But in that case I need to change the property name. I want to change the property name as well as database column name.

Answer (score 2):

Just rename property on your class. Create a EF migration. Most likely it will drop existing column you are trying to rename and add a new column. Replace that migration code with `RenameColumn("dbo.MyTableName", "OldColumnName", "NewColumnName");`

Comment: The problem is that this property is used by the framework. I can change in DB but not in class.

Comment: how? How the framework knows that he has to use MobileNumber property instead of PhoneNumber? Remember that its define in base identity class.

Comment: Oh, did not realise you are talking about property on `IdentityUser`. I would inherit `IdentityUser` and add a new properties on the inherited class - whichever ones you need. And don't bother with the inbuilt `PhoneNumber`

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit your model from IdentityUser class and add new property to it

```
 public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

}
```

and for renaming column in database use this code

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>()
         .Property(u => u.PhoneNumber)
         .HasColumnName("NewName");
}
```