# Changing Identity 2.0 table names database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, ef-database-first

So I managed to merge Identity 2.0 tables in my own database and I also changed the connection string so that now Identity uses my database. I did some test and it works fine.

**But how do I change table names??** because I looked over a couple of Identity classes in my project but none of them seems to have any table name inside..

at the moment table names start with `AspNet`. e.g `AspNetUserClames`. How do I change it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity

Comment: That's code first. It creates tables. I want the database first method.