# How to invoke DML trigger to customized OAuth2 table AspNetUser, when new user is created?

Tags: database, visual-studio, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, ssms

Thanks to [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity), I was able to customize the set of OAuth2 tables for user security.

Now I need to implement DML triggers to these customized tables, such as when a user is created, updated or deleted. What I need to do is to update and manipulate certain values in these tables, and ideally through database scripts and not in VS code.

Under SSMS/IIS10, is it possible to do so? The triggers I defined are current not invoked when a user is created through the web API.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Edited to add:
The triggers I have in mind are INSTEAD OF INSERT, INSTEAD OF UPDATE etc.

Comment: Providing more information, a scenario would be when a new user is being created, resulting in the following code called in `AccountController.cs`:      `IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); `

Comment: So, am I missing anything and is there a way to make such a call trigger the DML trigger residing in the database? The alternative is to implement this in the C# code but this is less preferable with the existing architecture.