# Using Asp.Net Identity with custom database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I copied default AspNet Identity tables (AspNetUsers, AspNetLogin etc) into my database and everything worked fine. Then I changed their names and made my own context with the following method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("tblUsers", "dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("tblRoles", "dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .ToTable("tblUserRoles", "dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("tblUserClaims", "dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .ToTable("tblUserLogins", "dbo");
    }
```

But it seems like the application is still looking for tables with old names as I'm getting error:

[image]

Please, tip me what are the neccessary changes that I haven't done ?

Comment: did you used the migration to update the database?

Answer (score 0):

According to [How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity) this should work:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("MyUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MyUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("MyUserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("MyUserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("MyUserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("MyRoles");
}
```

also make sure you're not falling into a trap that ASP.NET Identity uses its default aspnetdb.mdf database and check your web.config for something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
   <add connectionString="yourdatabase" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```