# How to generate right migration on changed table names Asp.NET Core IdentityUser etc

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

It is possible to change table names of the IdentityUser, IdentityRole,... tables.

See [How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-identity)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("MyUsers");
}
```

But when I create new migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add new ApplicationIdentity
```

The migration is generated for the original names:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
            });
```

It is possible to change generated migration manually, but is there any trick how to generate migration with correct names?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the migration manually:

- Add Empty migration file by using the below command

  ```
   dotnet ef migrations add rename_tables
  ```
- A new file will add to migration and you need to change it as the below

  ```
  public partial class rename_tables : Migration
  {
   protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
   {
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetRoleClaims", newName: "RoleClaims");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetRoles", newName: "Roles");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetUserLogins", newName: "UserLogins");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetUserRoles", newName: "UserRoles");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetUsers", newName: "Users");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetUserTokens", newName: "UserTokens");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetUserClaims", newName: "UserClaims");
   }

   protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
   {
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "RoleClaims", newName: "AspNetRoleClaims");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "Roles", newName: "AspNetRoles");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "UserLogins", newName: "AspNetUserLogins");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "UserRoles", newName: "AspNetUserRoles");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "Users", newName: "AspNetUsers");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "UserTokens", newName: "AspNetUserTokens");
       migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "AspNetUserClaims", newName: "AspNetUserClaims");
    }
  }
  ```
- Finally you need to apply the migration

  ```
  dotnet ef database update
  ```

- This is will not change the constraints name but you can also added to you migration file

Answer (score -1):

You can do this on your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "Users");
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

    });
}
```

Will create this migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Users",
    columns: table => new
    {
        UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
        NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.UserId);
    });
```