# How can I rename Asp.net MVC identity tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net MVC and I want to rename identity tables such as **AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles** To Users, UserRole, UserwithRoles Please Can any one help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-identity)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

Data Annotations:

```
//Changing database table name to Metadata
[Table("Users")]
public class AspNetUsers
{
  [Required, Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required, StringLength(250), DataType(DataType.Text)]
  public string Name{ get; set; 
}
```

or we have Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  //Changing Database table name to Metadata
  modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>().ToTable("Users");
}
```

Using the Fluent API is the preferred option if you want to ensure your Domain Model stays uncluttered.

Answer (score 0):

You can give those tables a custom name of your choice in the `OnModelCreating` method within your `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file in the following way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // custom code here...

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken>().ToTable("UserToken", "dbo");

    // other custom code here...
}
```